# How to set offset when cropping images in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

My situation is the following:
I have about 7k images (they are all the same resolution)
that I need to crop with an offset of 2px x 2px y how can I archive this?
I already figured out how to run the command for every image in the directory.

I have also tried running

```
convert image.jpg -crop 97x97 cropped.jpg
```

It has no offset and it spits out several images instead of just the first cropped one.

Comment: Did you try `-crop 97x97+2+2` and does that work?

Comment: Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: I use Linux Mint.

Comment: "-crop 97x97+2+2" works thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find this works:

```
convert INPUT.JPG -crop 97x97+2+2 RESULT.JPG
```

If so, make a copy of a few files in a spare directory and try with:

```
cd spare
mogrify -crop 97x97+2+2 *.jpg
```

Or, if you want them done faster, use **GNU Parallel**:

```
cd spare
parallel mogrify -crop 97x97+2+2 {} ::: *.jpg
```